# How to upload videos to azure media services from smartphones

Tags: c#, azure

How to upload videos to azure media services from smartphones using c#? Is there any third party encoder present for mobile like wirecast present for laptop/desktop? Can we achieve this using rest api?

Comment: Want to ask clarifying question. Are you trying to broadcast/stream live event or you want to upload video recorded previously? For live broadcasting you can utilize component supporting RTPM protocol. See workflow details utilizing WireCast at http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/18/azure-media-services-rtmp-support-and-live-encoders/.

Comment: trying to broadcast/stream live. I've done it on laptop using wirecast. But need to do it through smartphone. Thanks :)

Comment: For Iphone you can check http://mingfeiy.com/using-iphone-live-stream-azure-media-services . What mobile platform are you targeting? Iphone and Android have third party libraries to stream using RTMP protocol. For windows phone check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319378/rtmp-c-sharp-client-library thread

Comment: Thank u George :) . For iphone too i can use wirecast great. For andriod i need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Due to low bandwidth on mobile devices it's not preferable to upload the videos from the mobile. Also I am not sure if there is any third party application to achieve the same  but it can be done. The following code works fine for the windows Phone an Xamirin App Development

```
    // Part 1 - Connect to Media Services
  //          Setup upload progress event
  //          Upload a video to encode
  CloudMediaContext mediaContext =
    new CloudMediaContext("[ ACCOUNT NAME ]","[ ACCOUNT KEY ]");
  mediaContext.Assets.OnUploadProgress += Assets_OnUploadProgress;
  var asset = mediaContext.Assets.Create(    
    @"C:\windows\Performance\WinSat\winsat.wmv");
  // Part 2 - Create a task, specify encoding details
  Console.Clear();
  IJob job = mediaContext.Jobs.CreateJob("Sample Job");
  var expressionEncoder = mediaContext.MediaProcessors.Where(
    mp => mp.Name == "Expression Encoder").Single();
  var task = job.Tasks.Add(
    mediaProcessor: expressionEncoder,
    configuration: "H.264 HD 720p VBR");
  task.Inputs.Add(asset);
  task.Outputs.Add("Sample Task Output Asset");
  // Part 3 - Submit the encoding job to begin processing
  while (job.State != JobState.Finished)
  {
    job = mediaContext.Jobs.Refresh(job.Id);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("Job Name: " + job.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Job ID: " + job.Id);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Job State: {0,-20}", job.State);
    Console.WriteLine("Task Progress: {0:0.00}%  ",
      job.Tasks.Single().Progress);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Job Complete!");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Don't forget to add [Media Service SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/develop/media-services/developer-tools/) via Nugget Package Manager.